# WildFly not persisting stored procedure call in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ejb, wildfly

I'm developing an EJB 3 application running on a WildFly 8 with MySQL. I need to update a counter (`receiptCounter`) within an entity (`User`) and decided to try it with a stored procedure call to avoid race conditions.

This is how I created the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE increment_receipt_counter
(
   IN userID_in INT
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE User SET receiptCounter = receiptCounter + 1 WHERE id = userID_in;
    SELECT receiptCounter AS receiptCounter_new FROM User WHERE id = userID_in;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is how I call it:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;
...
public int incrementReceiptsCounter(int userID) throws InvalidEntityException, UnauthorizedException
{
    StoredProcedureQuery q = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("increment_receipt_counter");
    q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("userID_in", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    q.setParameter("userID_in", userID);
    q.executeUpdate();
    return (Integer)q.getSingleResult();
}
```

The strange thing is: When called from Java, the procedure returns the correct new counter value, but the new value is not getting persisted in the database. For example, if the receiptCounter was 1 in the DB before calling the procedure, the procedure call in Java returns 2, but the User table in the DB still shows a value of 1. When I call the procedure directly from the MySQL command line, it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing commit?

Answer (score 0):

In the mysql command line `auto commit` may be enabled meaning your update is persisted automatically.

In the java connection you probably disable the `auto commit`, therefore the update is not committed, but the `select` running in the same transaction as the `update`, still returns the updated value.

However, if you want to handle concurrency, then you should have a `select ... for update` first to lock the counter, then update the value.

Comment: Just a note on transaction, if he is using user managed transaction, then this scenario can occur. If he is using container managed transaction, then auto commit should be called automatically and the problem may lie somewhere else